# Little Problem in an fairly simple program

Tags: c++

Ok, so i am a novice in programming, and i'm having trouble on this one. The intent of the program is to create a program that asks the user to enter any number other than the number equal to the number of times they've been asked to enter a number. e.g  don't press 0, don't press 1, don't press 2... until you press it. So, in order for the program to exit, should press the respective number.

The only problem is that the program seems to recognised no only the number in question but the next number too. e.g :" don't press 0 " the program will recognise **0 and 1** as a valid number and will exit the program. I can't see why.

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
   int x;      
   for (int y=0;y<=100;y++) {
      if  (x != y){
        cout << "Don't press " << y<< " :";
        cin >> x;
      } 
      if (x==y) {
        cout << "Hey, You weren't supposed to press " << y;
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Thank you guy for the answers, the problem was in the first (and apparently useless) conditional. (Thank you Tobias)
Here's the new code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main () {

int x;


for (int y=0;y<100;y++){

cout << "Dont press " << y << ":";
cin >> x;
if (x==y) {
cout <<"Hey, you shouldn't have pressed " <<y;
break;
}
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `x` before you give input to `x`? It's *indeterminate* (and could be seen as almost random or as "garbage"). And using indeterminate values in C++ leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to rethink your design (I'm thinking the `if (x != y)` part is not needed).

Comment: `x` is not initialised. Oops.

Comment: In addition to forgetting to initialize x, try looking at your loop and pretending the user entered "1" and see what happens the next iteration of the loop...

Comment: Why are you checking `x != y` before you even get the new `y`?